# What namespace is CWnd in?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

My biggest complaint about the MS docs is they don't say what actually contains what class you're looking at. OpenCV is like the gold standard of docs. Tells you the whole function, and what header file it's located in.

For those of us that haven't been doing this for 20 years, I don't just know where this is at and it's difficult to google without noise.

What namespace is `CWnd` in?

Comment: `CWnd` is a very old MFC class. AFAIK It is not defined in a namespace (so it's considered in the global namespace).

Comment: So if I do #include <windows.h> it's supposed to just be there?

Comment: fwiw, the header is in the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=msvc-170#requirements

Comment: Not sure about the header. I think there were specific MFC headers (maybe afxwin.h).

Comment: Nope! wasn't that one (but I'll go dig I wouldn't expect any additional help). This is what I meant though. This space is rough because too many people are too good and have been doing this for too long. Too many simple things fall through the cracks because everyone has this sort of shared knowledge. Something as simple as "how do include a super common c++ header" becomes very complicated.

edit: well maybe it is this one. I'd be surprised if I missed an include path

Comment: Why do you actually use MFC ? There are better alternatives these days IMHO. E.g.: write a thin wrapper around your c++ code with c++/cli, then implement the GUI in C# (where you can use your c++/cli wrapper directly). Implementing GUI in C# (WinForms for sure, maybe WPF) is significantly more conveninent than with MFC.

Comment: @wohlstad Why are there not more articles around showing how to achieve the same thing as you describe, targeted at MFC users? Atleast it is all maintained inside the one project in MFC. And my appTranslator which I need only works with MFC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `CWnd` being a legacy MFC class, is not defined in any namespace, and therefore considered as belonging to the **global namespace**.
2. In order to use it you need to `#include <afxwin.h>`, as you can see in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=msvc-170#requirements).

Comment: That was it! I'm doing a cmake project. I'd bet half this is handled for you in native projects.